# Validation rule preventing going back in Oppty stages while allowing user to close deals

Tags: validation-rule

I am trying to create a validation rule for Oppty object that:

- Prevents users from going back in Oppty stages unless user has certain types of profile
- Still allows users to close lost or won deals

Below is what I tried, and while it prevents users from moving back in stages it also does not allow users to close won/lost deals.

```
AND(
    CASE(
        StageName, 
        "Initial Stage", 1, 
        "Second Stage", 2, 
        "Third Stage", 3, 
        "Closed", 4,
        0
    )
    <
    CASE(
        PRIORVALUE(StageName),
        "Initial Stage", 1, 
        "Second Stage", 2, 
        "Third Stage", 3, 
        "Closed", 4,
        0
    ), 
    /*Profile Type1*/
    $Profile.Id != '000000', 

    /*Profile Type2*/
    $Profile.Id != '000000'
)
```

Any insight or advice is deeply appreciated. Thank you so much and happy Friday!

Comment: This looks to be most of the way there (though you may want to consider using a custom permission instead of relying on profile ids). Can you please [edit] your question to add more detail about what your closed-lost/closed-won stage names are?

Comment: @DerekF Your comment made me realize where I went wrong! Thank you so much for taking the time to help. :) I also haven't considered using a custom permission and will definitely look into it.